# How to get IP from ContainerRequestContext JERSEY 2.1?

Tags: java, request, jersey, ip

My code is this:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException 
  {
   // can I get Ip from request?????

 }
```

How can I get ip address from `request`?

Answer (score 18):

According to this [JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960) ticket, based on this [discussion](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Injection-of-HttpServletRequest-Context-in-ContainerRequestFilter-does-not-work-td7580818.html), they added support for injecting the `HttpServletRequest` into your filter, a code snippet from the above JIRA looks like this:

```
public class MyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

You can then use the `HttpServletRequest` API to get the Remote IP, see the full [Javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()), excerpt:

> getRemoteAddr
>
> java.lang.String getRemoteAddr()
>
> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request. For HTTP servlets, same as the value of the CGI variable REMOTE_ADDR.
>
> Returns:
>
> a String containing the IP address of the client that sent the request

Comment: did not worked for me :(
I'm having the following error :
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to create a Proxy for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest in scope org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped an error occured while creating the proxy`

Comment: My servlet is empty and therefore I can't get the remote IP. Anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: This is the same issue we are facing. Any update on this?

Comment: What version of Jersey 2.0 does this work?  `2.25.1` does not work for me.

Comment: Also, the JIRA ticket link is dead.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail?