# Apache CXF 2.7 context passing issues

Tags: java, filter, jersey, jax-rs, cxf

I wrote a logging filter and pass around certain information from ContainerRequestContext to WriterInterceptorContext using the setProperty() function of ContainerRequestContext.

I am able to retrieve the property I set using getProperty when using with a Jersey implementation.

But the same does not work with the Apache CXF 2.7. Any inputs?

```
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter,WriterInterceptor {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
  reqContext.setProperty("sampleProperty", "sampleValue");
}

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
 if (context.getProperty("sampleProperty") != null) { -> passes for jersey, fails for Apache CXF 2.0
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to get the context.

```
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter,WriterInterceptor {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
  reqContext.setProperty("sampleProperty", "sampleValue");
}

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    Message message = JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage();
    ContainerRequestContext reqContext = new ContainerRequestContextImpl(message.getExchange().getInMessage(),
            false, true);
 if (reqContext.getProperty("sampleProperty") != null) { 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a cleaner way to get the context [here on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28281097/166524):

```java
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter,WriterInterceptor {
  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
}
```

and then use directly `servletRequest.getAttribute(name)`.